# Falling Images in Javascript (Images Falling Too Rapidly)

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

The following code works when the function is called for the first time. However, when I call the setup() function again, the speed increases (the images fall more rapidly). I'm trying to figure out how to maintain the initial speed without it increasing speed every time the function is called. I've been working with this for days.  Any help will be appreciated.

(Why I need this: I'm working on a feature that allows the user to switch between 4 different types of falling images. The user will click on an image, which will trigger the function. However, each time the user clicks the fall speed increases.)

```
 <canvas id="canvasRegn" width="1000" height="450"style="margin:100px;position:relative;z-index:999999;opacity:0.2;">
```

```
var ctx;
var imgBg;
var imgDrops;
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var noOfDrops = 50;
var fallingDrops = [];


function drawBackground(){  
    ctx.drawImage(imgBg, 0, 0); //Background
}

function draw() {
    drawBackground();

    for (var i=0; i< noOfDrops; i++)
    {
    ctx.drawImage (fallingDrops[i].image, fallingDrops[i].x, fallingDrops[i].y); //The rain drop

    fallingDrops[i].y += fallingDrops[i].speed; //Set the falling speed
    if (fallingDrops[i].y > 450) {  //Repeat the raindrop when it falls out of view
    fallingDrops[i].y = -25 //Account for the image size
    fallingDrops[i].x = Math.random() * 1000;    //Make it appear randomly along the width    
    }

    }
}

function setup() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasRegn');

    if (canvas.getContext) {
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                imgBg = new Image();
        imgBg.src = "/BACKGROUND.png";
    setInterval(draw, 36);
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfDrops; i++) {
        var fallingDr = new Object();
        fallingDr["image"] =  new Image();


    fallingDr.image.src = '/image.png';


        fallingDr["x"] = Math.random() * 1000;
        fallingDr["y"] = Math.random() * 5;
        fallingDr["speed"] = 3 + Math.random() * 5;
        fallingDrops.push(fallingDr);
        }

    }
}




setup();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not cancelling the previous `setInterval`. After the second `setup` call you are executing `draw` twice as many times per unit time and so on.

```
...
var fallingDrops = [];
var timer = null;

...

clearInterval(timer);
timer = setInterval(draw, 36);

...
```

Answer (score 0):

The setInterval calls could be stacking up on each other, causing drawBackground to happen more often than you think.

Create a variable to hold your 'setInterval':

```
var drawRepeater = setInterval(draw, 36);
```

And add a clearInterval before you re-call the setInterval:

```
clearInterval(drawRepeater);
var drawRepeater = setInterval(draw, 36);
```

Comment: You are correct about the reason for the described behaviour, but your code is wrong. The return value of `setInterval` cannot be stored in a local variable. On the next execution of `setup` the value of the variable will be `undefined` when passed to `clearInterval`.